# TypeError: expected string or buffer - In Re.Sub

Tags: python, pyodbc, smtplib

The full error is this:

```
  File "C:\scripts\WDItemAddEmail.py", line 68, in <module>
    send_email(execQuery)
  File "C:\scripts\WDItemAddEmail.py", line 66, in send_email
    s.sendmail(email_sender, email_recipient, msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 749, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 507, in data
    q = quotedata(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 167, in quotedata
    re.sub(r'(?:\r\n|\n|\r(?!\n))', CRLF, data))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here is my code:
I am trying to send an email with the results of a query and I am getting an error with the email part.
I am not sure if the sendemail() method is causing the issue or not.

```
def execQuery(server, database, query):
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        for row in rows:
            results = """<td>"""+row[0]+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row[4]+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row[5]+"""</td>
            \n"""
            
        
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
        return results
    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        return "<td>Execution failed.</td>"
        

def send_email(execQuery):
    results = execQuery(server, database, query)
    email_sender = 'x@x.com'
    email_recipient = 'x@x.com'
    email_subject = "WD New Item(s) Added"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_sender
    msg['To'] = email_recipient
    msg['Subject'] = email_subject
    
    html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>GUID</th>
                <th>Part Number</th>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                """+results+"""
            </tr>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>"""
    
    body = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(body)
    
    s = smtplib.SMTP(SMTPserver)
    s.sendmail(email_sender, email_recipient, msg)
    s.quit()
send_email(execQuery)
```

Comment: there is no re.sub in your code!

Comment: The `msg` argument must be a string - probably using `str(msg)` should do the trick - it should convert the message into the correct string format.

Comment: I was referring to the `msg` argument of `sendmail()`, in case this was not clear.

Comment: This worked! Thank you sir!

Comment: You might be able to send the message object without stringifying it using the[send_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message) method.